# What type of group to choose in OpenLDAP for grouping users

Tags: ldap, openldap

I need to know what kind of group should I use for grouping users in LDAP.

I basically need the function MemberOf, to get some permissions based on groups membership.

Example:

- Users

  - User 1
  - User 2
  - User 3
- Groups

  - Group 1
  - Group 2

User 1 is member of Group 1 and Group 2.

The groups need to be dynamic, like Active Directory.

The questions comes because I have these for choose:

`Samba: Group Mapping`

`User Group`

`Generic: Posix Group`

The same goes for Users, which one should I choose?

`Generic: User Account`

`Samba: Account`

I can't find a good site where the differences are shown, any link will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

LDAP/X.500 defines only *group objects* which have *member attributes*, the inverse relation where a user object has a *memberof* attribute in OpenLDAP can be achieved with the [`memberof` overlay](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/overlays.html#Reverse%20Group%20Membership%20Maintenance). NDS/eDir and AD make this happen by magic. LDAP proper does not define dynamic bi-directional member/group objects/attributes. Related to that overlay is the [refint](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/overlays.html#Referential%20Integrity) overlay which helps complete the illusion (and also addresses the mildly irritating problem of a group always requiring at least one member).

There are generally two interesting group types to pick, `groupOfNames` or `groupOfUniqueNames`, the first one `GroupOfNames` is suitable for most purposes. The latter, `groupOfUniqueNames`, has a slightly esoteric feature: it allows the member [DN to contain a numeric UID suffix](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2252#section-6.21), to preserve uniqueness of members across time should DNs be reassigned to different entities. Neither form enforces unique DNs in the list of members.

Other types of groups have distinct purposes (defined by schema and application). A less common group-type object is [RFC 2256](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2256.txt) *roles* (`organizationalRole` type, with `roleOccupant` attribute), this is implicitly used for role-based access control, but is otherwise similar to the other group types (thanks to [EJP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/207421/ejp) for the tip).

The `posixGroup` type represents the conventional unix groups, identified by a `gidNUmber` and listing `memberUid'`s. It is not a general purpose group object in the DIT, it's up to the application (i.e. the LDAP client layer) to implement/observe it.

When it comes to user accounts, account object-types should not be thought of as exclusive, each type typically adds attributes to a user object in a compatible way (though an `objectClass` *can* be exclusive if it's *structural*, that's not something you'll often have to worry about generally).

Comment: There is also `organizationalRole`.

Comment: Thanks I installed both and it is still asking for one Member on groupOfNames. Did I do anything wrong? I wil try using posixGroup now, I am using PHPLDAPAdmin

Comment: `posixGroup` is to facilitate unix style groups, it contains a list of uids, just like `/etc/group`, I don't think it will help you here. Both of the two common groups I mentioned *must* have at least one member. Otherwise, if you're having trouble getting the `memberof` overlay to work post your config as a new question.